# Automatic rearrangement issue of dates in excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula

If my date is "Sep-01-2015" it should return dd-mm-yyyy. Which can be done by cell formatting settings.

But what if my date I want to enter and print is the same "11-Jan-2021"? I want to type 11/01/2021 and format cell to 11-Jan-2021. I know I can use format cell  option to convert date format or use custom format. But that is not my question.

When I'm typing the cell is re-arranging terms **like 11/01/2021 as 01-Nov-21 where it should be 01-Jan-21**.

Also, I want to keep regional setting in the code and not manual adjustments. If you find any VBA date format code to set the date in "en-US" or for any regional preferences please add your answer below.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on you computer local date format settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you  input will always be parsed according to your locale ("Windows Regional Settings"): I have UK english locale so if I *format* a cell `mm/dd/yyyy` and enter `11/1` it interprets it with reference to my locale (so entering `11/1` is parsed as `11th Jan 2021`) but displays it as `01/11/2021`
2. In the highlighted line, you have not explcitly declared a format in `& Format(dtmDate) &` and so it will format that according to the locale - so if it is only a display issue then explicitly put the date format here, e.g.  `& Format(dtmDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") &`

Comment: Thanks for your response, @JohnnieL . Your solution is partially right. I tried - sht.PageSetup.CenterFooter = strDateTR & ": " & Format(dtmDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & Chr(10) & strRDateTR & ": " & Format(dtmReview, "dd-MMM-yyyy") & Chr(10) & strTempversionTR

Comment: But I'm searching for VBA code where I can change the regional date settings to en-US. So the user doesn't have to worry if its computer setting is in US format or not, the code will take the date and set the filter to en-US format and add in footer. If you find something please do share.

Comment: This "& Format(dtmDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") &" is not working for everyone. Hope you got my problem.

Comment: I believe that you ***either*** need to set the user's locale ("Windows Regional Settings" - this is ***not*** an excel thing but system) ***or*** you force to a string using `format` with the date format that you want - at that point the date is no longer a date but a string and so will not be affected by locale

Comment: ***>  I'm searching for VBA code where I can change the regional date settings to en-US. So the user doesn't have to worry if its computer setting is in US format or no***

at the point you use `format` you get a string so can you not jus set the format to be US style there? `format(dtmDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")`?

Comment: ( https://codekabinett.com/images/format-date-language-country-vba-access/date-format-output-immediate-pane.png )(    https://codekabinett.com/images/format-date-language-country-vba-access/date-format-output-query.png ) These are two links which say windows regional settings can be adjusted from code. I still have issues with this code. It is not working, some syntax issues. Please can you check

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final and easy answer to my question.

I tried the above solution also, it was useful for me but not for all the users. Some of my colleagues were still facing the issues with some regions.

Then I found that the VB macro was working right with this code: *& Format(dtmDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") &*. But along with that we also need to **change the cell formating to text.**

Like this [image]

So, now whatever you enter it will be taken as it is for macros to process and produce the output irrespective of your system settings.

Like you can see in the image above, I have entered 2/01/2023 and converted to text from cell formatting. VB macros already is in *& Format(dtmDate, "dd-mmm-yyyy") &* this format.The 3 Ms means month in three letters like Jan.

Hence, my output will be [image]

Hope you get it.
Thanks.